# Doing something like psframebox in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I used the following code to typeset the figure below with `pstricks`. Is there something like this that works with `tikz`? I tried to do this and discovered `\node`s that can be filled with text, but I think these nodes cannot be nested.

```
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(11,1.8)
     \rput[bl](0,0){%  
\psset{fillstyle=solid, framearc=0.25,framesep=5pt}
\psframebox{%
\psframebox{%
       \psframebox{alle}
       \psframebox{Studenten}}
\psframebox{lesen}
\psframebox{%
   \psframebox{während}
   \psframebox{%
       \psframebox{dieser}
       \psframebox{Zeit}}}
 \psframebox{Bücher}}}
 \end{pspicture}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this in TikZ the `fit` library or, if you dare, by nesting `tikzpicture`s (which should be avoided, if possible since it could produce undesired results). Below I present the original PS-Tricks version and the two TikZ variations:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning}

\tikzset{
frbox/.style={
  rounded corners,
  draw,
  thick,
  inner sep=5pt
  }
}

\newcommand\TZbox[1]{\tikz\node[frbox,baseline] {#1};}

\begin{document}

With \texttt{PS-Tricks}:\par\medskip

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(11,1.8)
     \rput[bl](0,0){%  
\psset{fillstyle=solid, framearc=0.25,framesep=5pt}
\psframebox{%
\psframebox{%
       \psframebox{alle}
       \psframebox{Studenten}}
\psframebox{lesen}
\psframebox{%
   \psframebox{während}
   \psframebox{%
       \psframebox{dieser}
       \psframebox{Zeit}}}
 \psframebox{Bücher}}}
 \end{pspicture}\par\bigskip

With \texttt{TikZ} and the \texttt{fit} library:\par\medskip

\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=2pt and 3pt,
every node/.style={frbox}  
]
\node (alle) {alle};
\node[right=of alle] (studenten) {Studenten};
\node[fit={(alle) (studenten)}] (fiti) {};
\node[right=of fiti] (lesen) {lesen};
\node[right=9pt of lesen] (wahrend) {während};
\node[right=9pt of wahrend] (dieser) {dieser};
\node[right=of dieser] (zeit) {Zeit};
\node[fit={(dieser) (zeit)}] (fitii) {};
\node[fit={(wahrend) (fitii)}] (fitiii) {};
\node[right=14pt of zeit] (bucher) {Bücher};
\node[fit={(fiti) (fitiii) (bucher)}] (fitvi) {};
\end{tikzpicture}\par\bigskip

With \texttt{TikZ} nesting nodes (careful!):\par\medskip

\TZbox{%
\TZbox{%
       \TZbox{alle}
       \TZbox{Studenten}}
\TZbox{lesen}
\TZbox{%
   \TZbox{während}
   \TZbox{%
       \TZbox{dieser}
       \TZbox{Zeit}}}
 \TZbox{Bücher}}

\end{document}
```